# abi.encodeWithSignature did not work

Tags: solidity, abi

```
pragma solidity ^0.5.3;

contract SimpleFallback{
    event FallbackCalledEvent(bytes data);
    event AddEvent(uint a, uint b, uint result);
    event DoubleEvent(uint a, uint b);
    event GetNameEvent(string);

    function() external{
        emit FallbackCalledEvent(msg.data);
    }

    function add(uint a, uint b) public returns(uint){
        // assert(a >= 0);
        // assert(b >= 0);
        // assert(a + b > a && a + b > b);

        uint _result = a + b;
        emit AddEvent(a, b, _result);

        return _result;
    }

    function double(uint a) public returns(uint){
        // assert(a >= 0);
        // assert(2*a >= 0 && 2*a >= a);
        uint _result = 2*a;

        emit DoubleEvent(a, _result);

        return _result;
    }

    function getName(string memory name) public returns(string memory){
        emit GetNameEvent(name);

        return name;
    }
}


contract RunTest{


    function callAddlTest(address other) public {
        // bytes4 messageId = bytes4(keccak256("add(uint, uint)"));
        // other.call(messageId, 5, 60);
        other.call(abi.encodeWithSignature("add(uint,uint)", 85, 60));
    }

    function callDoublelTest(address other) public {
        // bytes4 messageId = bytes4(keccak256("add(uint, uint)"));
        // other.call(messageId, 5, 60);
        other.call(abi.encodeWithSignature("double(uint)", 100));
    }

    function callgetNameTest(address other) public{
        other.call(abi.encodeWithSignature("getName(string)", "hello"));
    }
}
```

**Operation as below.**

- Step 1. deploy 2 contracts;
- Step 2. call `callAddlTest` whit contract SimpleFallback's address, event log is as below, which showed that called add() failed, the fallback function was triggered.

```
[
    {
        "from": "0x038f160ad632409bfb18582241d9fd88c1a072ba",
        "topic": "0x5cd57a899be814fb3a40e18f9d1ba77420bbd22073d35165511f750aa70538b6",
        "event": "FallbackCalledEvent",
        "args": {
            "0": "0xb89663520000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000055000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000003c",
            "data": "0xb89663520000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000055000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000003c",
            "length": 1
        }
    }
]
```

- Step 3. call `callDoubleTest` whit contract SimpleFallback's address, event log is as below, which showed that called double() failed, the fallback function was triggered.

```
[
    {
        "from": "0x038f160ad632409bfb18582241d9fd88c1a072ba",
        "topic": "0x5cd57a899be814fb3a40e18f9d1ba77420bbd22073d35165511f750aa70538b6",
        "event": "FallbackCalledEvent",
        "args": {
            "0": "0xd524bc570000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000064",
            "data": "0xd524bc570000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000064",
            "length": 1
        }
    }
]
```

- Step 4. call `callgetNameTest` whit contract SimpleFallback's address, event log is as below, which showed that called getName() successfully.

```
    {
        "from": "0x038f160ad632409bfb18582241d9fd88c1a072ba",
        "topic": "0x26c73f7f14382f5db0b9f94dd29ff8938f2e4be69fb13e0825ece287e8e538d5",
        "event": "GetNameEvent",
        "args": {
            "0": "hello",
            "length": 1
        }
    }
]
```

**Question:**

for call(abi.encodeWithSignature()), why:
  - 1)`other.call(abi.encodeWithSignature("add(uint,uint)", 85, 60));` did not work? 
  - 2)`other.call(abi.encodeWithSignature("double(uint)", 100));` did not work?
  - 3)`other.call(abi.encodeWithSignature("getName(string)", "hello"));` did work? 
  - 4) does `encodeWithSignature` not support multiple parameters, compared 1) and 3)?
       and does `encodeWithSignature` not support a uint parameters, compared 2) and 3)?

Answer (score 5):

I already found out the root cause. It should use the full names of the types, not their aliases, so it should be `uint256` instead of `uint`.

Comment: OMG, thank you for this. I just spent ~3 hours trying to understand why my staticcall is always failing.

Comment: I think `encodeWithSignature` shuold provide better friendly interface, fox example, `abi.encodeWithSignature("add(uint,uint)")` and `abi.encodeWithSignature("add(uint,  uint)")` are two different function signature, just because of spaces.

Answer (score 0):

```
(bool success, bytes memory response) = address(_address).call(abi.encodeWithSignature("transfer(address,address,uint256)", msg.sender, _to, _amount));
```

First argument should not contain any space in encodeWithSignature method.

Answer (score -1):

it's all about space

```
other.call(abi.encodeWithSignature("add(uint,uint)", 85, 60));
```

change it to:

```
other.call(abi.encodeWithSignature("add(uint,uint)",85,60));
```

Comment: I don't think there's a difference between those you provided

Comment: Yes, I know it's crazy.
But I test it, and it's working. Gives an error due to the space between ',' and the number

Comment: No, that's wrong. It would only have a difference if the space was in the function abi , eg `"add(uint,  uint)"`. The compiler doesn't care if there's a space between `85,  60`, it will run the same

Comment: I know, it should be exactly as you say. But I tested and it gave an error because of this space. Corrected when I deleted the space